# Changing AcceptButton depending on the selected numericUpDown control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two numericUpDown controls. Let's name one as Left and other as Right. And I have two buttons also will be named as Left and Right.

Initially Left button is the AcceptButton.

I want that if the user will change the Right numericUpDown then the Right button would be the AcceptButton.

I tried to set handler for ValueChanged event of numericUpDown controls but at first the contol is passed to Click event of the Left button because it is at this moment is the AcceptButton.

So how to do such a way that when the Left button is currently the AcceptButton and the user  changes the Right numericUpDown control and presses Enter key that the Right button would be the AcceptButton and its handler would get the control.

EDIT: it seems that nobody understand the problem So I will try to explain one more. When the user presses the Enter key then at first the control of the program is passed to the current AcceptButton and only after that it is passed to the handlers ValueChanged. So any settings of AcceptButton inside ValueChanged are in vain because the wrong button got already the control.

Comment: Are you asking how to have the actual button controls switched location wise? Could you not just change their labels then check the current value when the handler is called? If you could provide more detail on what you're trying to accomplish, there may be a better way of doing so.

Comment: @JWiley i do not change labels. I want to change the state of AcceptButton between two buttons depending on what numericUpDown control was used.

Comment: You're not providing much detail on what you're trying to do. Update your question with what you mean by "The Right button would be the AcceptButton", what happens to Left button in this case, and what you have defined for AcceptButton. Do you just want the same handler called every time despite different buttons?

Comment: How are you setting your form's accept button?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow please check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use common event handler for change event on both the controls and determine the actual sender with the help of "sender" argument. Based on the control name,  you can make your button active.

Comment: i do not see any sense in this approach. There is no problem to determine what numericUpDown control was changed. The problem is that when the used presses Enter key incorrect AcceptButton is activated.

Comment: In that case, you have to change default button for your form. You can use code as: `this.AcceptButton = btn_2` where btn_2 is your button name.

Comment: I explained in my question that this  does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        right_upDown.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(OnNumericUpDownValueChanged);
        left_upDown.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(OnNumericUpDownValueChanged);
        button_left.Click += new EventHandler(OnAcceptButtonClicked);
    }

    void OnAcceptButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void OnNumericUpDownValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == right_upDown)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button_right;
            button_left.Click -= OnAcceptButtonClicked;  //Un-register the event from the left
            button_right.Click += new EventHandler(OnAcceptButtonClicked); //Register the event on the right
        }
        else
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button_left;
            button_right.Click -= OnAcceptButtonClicked; //Un-register the event from the right
            button_left.Click += new EventHandler(OnAcceptButtonClicked); //Register the event on the left
        }
    }
```

Or you could do it this way if you prefer to use the AcceptButton Property:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        right_upDown.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(OnNumericUpDownValueChanged);
        left_upDown.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(OnNumericUpDownValueChanged);
        button_left.Click += new EventHandler(OnAcceptButtonClicked);
    }

    void OnAcceptButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void OnNumericUpDownValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AcceptButton -= OnAcceptButtonClicked;  //Un-register the event from the AcceptButton
        if (sender == right_upDown)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button_right;
        }
        else
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button_left;
        }

        this.AcceptButton += new EventHandler(OnAcceptButtonClicked); //Register the event on new AcceptButton
    }
```

Comment: Updated post with additional info, including event handler.

Comment: One more this does not work. I explained this in my question. When the user presses Enter key at first the control as passed to the current AcceptButton and only after that ValueChanged gets control.

Comment: I am sure there is a language problem here, but you are not explaining very well. Are you registering a click event on the AcceptButton somewhere? I changed my answer to reflect the need to change the event registration too.